# Safely upgrade PHP from 5.6.38 to PHP 7.2+ on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: apache2, php, php7

I am running a production server on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS which has PHP 5.6.38 installed. It's serving a PHP 5x application but because of `composer` and other requirements I need to upgrade it safely on latest version of PHP ([which from 6th December is PHP 7.3](http://php.net/archive/2018.php#id2018-12-06-1)) or at least 7.2.

I do not have the option to create a brand new server with latest PHP version and to migrate everything there. I need a safe and clean upgrade of PHP, only.

I have read [this article](https://tecadmin.net/install-php5-on-ubuntu/) which uses APT repository `ppa:ondrej/php` which allows multiple version of PHP. I do not want to preserve PHP 5.6.38 or have a multi-PHP environment.

My concern with using `ppa:ondrej/php` repo is how will it affect my existing Apache 2 configuration which is set up to work with PHP 5.6.38, and if I eventually do the upgrade with Ondrej's repo, what changes will I have to make in the Apache 2 configuration to make everything work again.

Also, will I have to reconfigure Apache 2 to work with PHP FPM?

As I said earlier, this is a production server, and unfortunatelly I do not have a staging/test/migration server as a failsafe solution.

Comment: Is there a backup for the app your serving and is it possible to set this up locally and test?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since it is a production server: **DO SOME BACKUPS**!!!

#### Add Ondrej's repo:

It's pretty safe to use `ppa:ondrej/php`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

#### Install PHP 7.3 and configure Apache2

You didn't mention if your current setup uses PHP FPM. It's not required to use FPM if you aren't interested in multi-PHP environment, so I presume you aren't. A safe way to migrate the PHP version Apache2 uses from 5.6 to 7.3 is:

```
sudo apt install php7.3
sudo a2enmod php7.3
sudo a2dismod php5.6
sudo service apache2 restart
```

#### Update PHP CLI:

You also mentioned `composer`. It uses PHP CLI, so you will have to install `php7.3-cli` package:

```
sudo apt install php7.3-cli
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.3
```

#### Clean up (optional):

When you are ready, make sure everything is working correctly.  It is not required, but if you want, you can remove the old PHP versions:

```
sudo apt purge php5.6*
sudo apt autoremove
```